# Создание юнит-теста в Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, юнит-тесты

Как сделать так (создать Unit Test):

[image]

В Visual Studio 2012

PS:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если мои данные не слишком устаревшие, то, к сожалению, эта функция была выпилена в VS11 (Visual Studio 2012), потому что она завязана на юнит-тесты MS Test, тогда как VS11 сделана так, чтобы одинаково хорошо работать с любым движков юнит-тестов (если его разработчики удосужились написать провайдер, конечно), в т.ч. NUnit, xUnit и т.п.

См. [аналогичный вопрос на stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547055/vs-11-ultimate-where-is-the-create-unit-tests-selection).

Answer (score 3):

Решение
[Enable “Create Unit Tests…” on Visual Studio 2012](http://dl.my/2013/enable-create-unit-tests-on-visual-studio-2012/)

Answer (score 1):

Установить Unit Test Generator скачав 
[отсюда](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/45208924-e7b0-45df-8cff-165b505a38d7)
или загрузить через Сервис>Расширения и обновления

После установки зайти в Тест>Configure Unit Test Generation и установить "Show on each run"